# How to remove NA from each row

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
data = structure(c(NA, NA, 42.5118650772641, 14.5479065259077, -1.8082256603085, 
23.5107343175811, 53.5663302164282, 29.9776538834842, -3.86496086519614, 
29.0845645318778, 97.3528292018692, 23.3881957633757, 54.8844183666383, 
28.4301700493692, 3.53001924175695, 15.8256931567166, 23.6987392522877, 
12.1185979190016, 2.48432380993373, 23.1776787033568, 30.0735375165638, 
10.6297705564003), .Dim = c(2L, 11L))
```

And I need to eliminate each NA element in the rows.
If I try to do

```
rem_NA =  data[!is.na(data)]
```

It will delete the NAs, but i will obtain a vector, but I don't want to lose the matrix form.

the output i would like to have is equal to:

```
data1 = data[,-1]
```

Comment: In your sample dataset, all `NA`s are aligned in column 1, so column 1 can be elimanted completely. But what result do you expect if the `NA`s are scattered arbitrarily, e.g., `matrix(c(NA, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA), nrow = 2L) `?

Comment: My goal is to eliminate each NA from each row, so in your case, the matrix would be: first row -->2,3. Second row --> 4,5. In this case the number of NA can't exceed one ofr each row, obviously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly from OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60997615/how-to-remove-na-from-each-row?noredirect=1#comment107916585_60997615), the positions of the `NA` values can be arbitrarily scattered but each row has the same number of `NA` values.

Here is an example for such a matrix:

```
m <- matrix(c(NA, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA), nrow = 2L, byrow = TRUE)
m
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
> [1,]   NA    2    3
> [2,]    4    5   NA
> ```

The `NA` values can be eliminated row-wise by

```
t(apply(m, 1L, na.omit))
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2]
> [1,]    2    3
> [2,]    4    5
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The following option seems to work:

```
data[, colSums(is.na(data)) < nrow(data)]
```

The logic here is to retain any column for which the number of `NA` values is strictly *less* than the number of rows.  The first column in your sample data fails this condition, because there are two rows and also two `NA` values.

Comment: Your answer removes only NAs if aligned in one column but the OP has requested "to eliminate each NA from each row" (also randomly distributed NAs). I admit that OP's sample dataset is somewhat misleading as the NAs are aligned in the first column.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `Filter` after converting to `data.frame`

```
Filter(function(x) any(!is.na(x)), as.data.frame(data))
```

Comment: Your answer removes only NAs if aligned in one column but the OP has requested "to eliminate each NA from each row" (also randomly distributed NAs). I admit that OP's sample dataset is somewhat misleading as the NAs are aligned in the first column.

Comment: @Uwe Your answer removes the `NA` from each row, but if there are unequal number of rows, it would return a list